# Draggable attribute and multiple monitors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my own custom popup window in my framework that is draggable using the draggable attribute.

Problem is, on multiple displays you can drag my window completely off the browser's screen and potentially break my web application (if the custom window is modal for example).

How can I stop the default draggable attribute from being dragged off onto another screen?

Comment: the viewport is limited by the web browser window so I can't see how you can drag outside...

Comment: Here's a screencast of my issue: http://screenr.com/X0pH

Comment: use jquery position, with collision:'fit fit' that should stop it going beyond the browser edge.

Answer (score 1):

The `.draggable()` function in **JQuery UI** has an option for [`containment`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment)

Here's an example of its usage

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/RF3Wd/)

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="child-container">
        <div class="draggable" id="d1">I'm stuck inside my parent</div>
        <div class="draggable" id="d2">I'm stuck inside the outer container</div>
    </div>
    <div class="draggable" id="d3">I'm stuck inside the document</div>
    <div class="draggable" id="d4">I can go anywhere!</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#container {
    margin: 20px;
    border-color: lime;
    height: 300px;
}
.child-container {
    border-color: red;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    height: 250px;
}
.draggable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-color: blue;
}
```

### JQuery

```
// Make draggable
$('.draggable').draggable();

// Add containment for each item
$('#d1').draggable('option', 'containment', 'parent');
$('#d2').draggable('option', 'containment', '#container');
$('#d3').draggable('option', 'containment', 'document');
$('#d4').draggable('option', 'containment', 'window');
```

Comment: I'm using `.attr("draggable", "Y")` so how can I incorporate these extra settings?

Comment: `$('.draggable').draggable('option', 'containment', 'document');`

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with your code that produces this error please?